# Changing custom post_type when publishing

Tags: custom-post-types

I would like to change the post_type from "prototyp" to "gutschein" when publishing a "prototyp" (clicking publish button of a "prototyp").

Is there a way to make this automatically by a function?

*Edit no.2:* **Don´t know why, but it still doesn´t seem to work (for me):**

```
function on_post_publish( $ID, $post ) {

    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }
if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'prototyp' ) {
    set_post_type( $post_id, 'gutschein' );
    }
}
add_action(  'publish_prototyp',  'on_post_publish', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Change `add_action(  'publish_post',` to `add_action(  'publish_prototyp',`,

Comment: No, that doesn´t work. The post_type stays the same, when publishing a "prototyp".

Comment: It works here, you may need other transition different to "publish". Read the documentation linked in @bueltge's answer.

Answer (score 0):

It give a hook to init your function for the requirements. The hook `{status}_{post_type}` is your right hook. If this hook was fired, you can start your custom function to change the post type. For your custom post type "prototyp" use `publish_prototyp`.

See also the codex about the hook, also the hook from old status to new status http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions

For the changing of the post type is the function `set_post_type` your right choice. See also the codex page for more information. 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_type

Comment: Hi, i´ve edited my post and added my first try. But this code seems to do nothing.

Comment: You use the wrong hook. If you use the custom post type "prototyp" then is the hook on publish a post of "prototyp" -- `publish_prototyp`.